# Invalid at the top level of the document error when reading XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting error like this.
The XML page cannot be displayed
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.
In the button click i wrote this.

```
String strUrl = "https://secure.dev.gateway.gov.uk/submission";    
HttpWebRequest req  = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( strUrl );
req.ContentType     = "text/xml";
req.Method          = "POST";
req.Accept          = "text/xml";
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials     = new NetworkCredential("189", "");
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

System.IO.Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
string strXML = GetXmlString("C:\\Documents and Settings\\com\\My Documents\\Downloads\\18march\\VatDecRequest_ValidSample v1.0.xml");
byte[] arrBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes( strXML );
stream.Write( arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length );
stream.Close();
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( respStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII );
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
string strResponse = rdr.ReadToEnd();
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(strResponse);
xmldoc.Save("C:\\test9.xml");
```

Comment: I think the error is in your xml file or stylesheet. Can you include them in your question (in case they are not too large)?

Comment: You are reading and writing ASCII - did you check that this is always true? Try using UTF-8 Encoding, it covers ASCII and can handle unicode if it comes up.

(the url in line 1 returns Unicode as far as I can see)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you loading the file as a string and then encoding it in ASCII? Why not just load the binary data and serve that directly? (`File.ReadAllBytes` is probably your friend.)

I suspect that the XML file is *actually* in UTF-8, quite possibly with a byte-order mark which can't be represented in ASCII.

The same goes for both the request and the response - where feasible just get the XML parser to deal with a binary stream and figure out the encoding for itself.